# How to get object from manytomany?

Tags: django, django-models

I have models:

```
class Z(models.Model):
    name = ...

class B(model.Model):
    something = model...
    other = models.ForeignKey(Z)

class A(models.Model):
    date = model.DateTimeField()
    objs_b = models.ManyToManyField(B)

    def get_obj_b(self,z_id):
        self.obj_b = self.objs_b.get(other=z_id)
```

and query:

```
qs = A.objects.filter(...)
```

but if I want get object B related to A I must call get_obj_b:

```
for item in gs:
    item.get_obj_b(my_known_z_id)
```

It was generate many queries. How to do it simple? I can not change models, and generally I must use filter (not my own manager) function.

Comment: so what are you trying to get? B objects based on  a certain Z.id and A criteria?

Comment: post, postlanguages, languages. One post may have many language specific data depending on the language. I want to get post and postlanguage(for current lang) data in one query. Models are what they are and I can not change them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django 1.4, I would suggest that you use prefetch_related like this:

```
A.objects.all().prefetch_related('objs_b__other')
```

This would minimize the number of queries to 2: one for model A, and one for 'objs_b' joined with 'other'

And you can combine it with a filter suggested by pastylegs:

```
A.objects.filter(objs_b__other__id=z_id).prefetch_related('objs_b__other')
```

For details see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related